# Creating a C++ mex function that can return a diagonal matrix

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I need to create a c++ mex function that input a matrix and return it diagonal with each array in its own block.
Ex.

```
input_matrix = ([1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9])

output_matrix = 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0
                0 0 0 4 5 6 0 0 0
                0 0 0 0 0 0 7 8 9
```

Can anyone help I am extremely lost at this point.

Comment: Is there a reason why you specifically need to use a mex function for this? Do you want the output to be a sparse or dense array?

Comment: “Where do I start” is not a very good question to ask on this site. Pick a MEX-file tutorial, write a MEX-file, think about how to create a matrix, try something, if you get stuck you can ask a specific question here, with code and a good understanding of the problem (but make sure it hasn’t been asked before).

Answer (score -1):

I made this example for you, the basic building block is std::vector.
A matrix can be modeled as a std::vector of std::vector.
std::vector is the C++ standard library type for dynamically allocated arrays

```
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// for fixed size arrays use templates, this will also ensure contiguous memory allocation
// to be compatible with other libraries
template<typename type_t, std::size_t rows_v, std::size_t cols_v>
auto create_diagonal_matrix(const type_t(&input)[rows_v][cols_v])
{
    // unlike "C" style arrays std::array can be returned from a function
    std::array<std::array<type_t,cols_v*rows_v>, rows_v> matrix;

    std::size_t prefix_size = 0ul;                         // number of zeros in front of the next row
    std::size_t postfix_size = (rows_v - 1ul) * cols_v;    // how many zeros to append at the end of next row;

    for (std::size_t row = 0ul; row < rows_v; ++row)
    {
        std::size_t col = 0ul;

        // fill prefix_size indices with 0
        for (std::size_t n = 0ul; n < prefix_size; ++n, ++col) matrix[row][col] = 0;

        // fill input row size entries with values from the input
        for (std::size_t n = 0ul; n < rows_v; ++n, ++col) matrix[row][col] = input[row][n];

        // then fill postfix_size indices with 0
        for (std::size_t n = 0ul; n < postfix_size; ++n, ++col) matrix[row][col] = 0;

        // adjuest the prefix and postfix sizes
        prefix_size += rows_v;
        postfix_size -= rows_v;
    }

    return matrix;
}


auto create_diagonal_matrix_dynamic(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& input)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;
    assert(input.size() > 0);
    auto row_size = input[0].size();

    std::size_t prefix_size = 0ul;                                  // number of zeros in front of the next row
    std::size_t postfix_size = (input.size() - 1ul) * row_size;    // how many zeros to append at the end of next row;

    for (const auto& row : input)
    {
        assert(row.size() == row_size);                             // runtime validation, all rows must have same length
        std::vector<int> new_row;

        // fill prefix_size indices with 0
        for (std::size_t n = 0ul; n < prefix_size; ++n) new_row.push_back(0);

        // fill input row size entries with values from the input
        for (std::size_t n = 0ul; n < row_size; ++n) new_row.push_back(row[n]);

        // then fill postfix_size indices with 0
        for (std::size_t n = 0ul; n < postfix_size; ++n) new_row.push_back(0);

        matrix.push_back(new_row);

        // adjuest the prefix and postfix sizes
        prefix_size += row_size;
        postfix_size -= row_size;
    }

    return matrix;
}

int main()
{
    // use an initializer list to setup the 2D input array
    // I think in your code this should be done through parsing an input string
    // and then build up a std::vector<std::vector<int>> yourself.
    auto matrix = create_diagonal_matrix({ {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} });

    // output the generated matrix.
    for (const auto& row : matrix)
    {
        bool comma = false;
        for (const auto& value : row)
        {
            if (comma) std::cout << ", ";
            std::cout << value;
            comma = true;
        }

        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // to show memory is contiguous in std::array<std::array<int,9>,3>
    // this is how to get access to contiguous memory for std::array
    auto data_ptr = matrix.data();

    for (std::size_t row = 0; row < matrix.size(); row++)   
    {
        bool comma = false;

        for (std::size_t col = 0; col < matrix[0].size(); col++)
        {
            if (comma) std::cout << ", ";
            std::cout << data_ptr[row][col];    
            comma = true;
        }

        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    // creating a mex file is desribed here 
    // https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/c-mex-source-file.html

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not make a MEX-file. Also, a vector of vectors is a terrible way to store a matrix, and will be incompatible with any matrix library I know of. It is much better to use a single block of memory (a regular vector) and map its indices to array indices: `i + j*nRows`.

Comment: How to create a MEX file is not a C++ question and is described here : https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/c-mex-source-file.html. 
vector of vector is not a terrible way (even matlab example uses it) and still prefered over typing new/delete yourself. Anyway, I did make a contiguous memory example using templates but felt the template code would distract from the algorithm for filling the matrix. I've now included the template code in the example.